# AMP wordpress plugin and detecting mobile device via .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, amp-html

I've setup an AMP version of my website and have tested it via the browser and it's working ok using the AMP wordpress plugin.  I then went to add some code to my .htaccess file to detect mobile devices and rewite to the /amp/ version. Please advise if I have a mistake in my .htacess code as I can't get mobile devices to detect my amp version.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#AMP Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot\-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|\#opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/amp/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What's the reason for setting up the redirect?  The 'normal' integration is with a `<link rel="amphtml">` tag pointing to your AMP version, then anyone who wants to see/index that instead can do that.  Are you hoping to make your AMP into a mobile site?  You might find that the requirements of each aren't really compatible.

Comment: If the user comes from a search engine, they would get redirected.  I'm trying to give a better user experience to people that click a link on another website or find the website from social media.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your amp version is under /amp (http://example.com/amp), this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot\-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|\#opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ https://example.com/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include mobile detection library
So, you can use AMPforWP plugin

for redirection. 
This things are already have in this plugin